# Retrieve data from infopath form to nintex workflow

Tags: sharepoint-2007, infopath, nintex-workflow

I'm new to Nintex Workflow 2007. I am publishing inforpath 2007 form inside Library and assign a Nintex workflow.

Inforpath form contains `'approve'` and `'Reject'` buttons. Some parties will get tasks to approve the form via workflow. When someone 'Approve' or 'reject' it the information will remain in inforpath form. (Approver approve it only using form buttons)

I just want to access that information and do some implementation in workflow. 
Ex- Set a Condition (If Approved do something Else Do something else)

Is someone know a way to access inforpath form information and use it in workflow.?

Same scenario  is possible to do with flags. When someone approve it, we can set a flag to list and access that flag in workflow. However I want to know a way to directly access inforpath form and get information from itself.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to do this. You can find 'Query XML' control in Nintex. Using this control , this able to access InfoPath control's Xpath.

You can copy your InfoPath control (radio button) XPath by right clicking on it and choose copy XPath. Then you can use it in Nintex. And put that outcome to your variable. This is cool way to do this.